# Can't edit anything on FTP server

Tags: nautilus, ftp, 14.10

I have a serious problem. When at work, I work directly on our development FTP server, using sublime text.

However, since upgrading to 14.10, I can't edit anything on any server. Creating new folders or files will make nautilus jump to my home folder, and then when entering the ftp server again, it will crash. This part seems similar to this bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1385919). However I have the same problem when creating or saving files.

When I create a file through the nautilus right click menu, a similar incident will happen - however when I try to save with Sublime, it'll show me a popup asking if I want to write to a protected file. At this point, I have noticed that nautilus once again have changed to my home folder - and when I press overwrite, it states that the file can't be found. I have tried letting nautilus crash and reopen it before pressing overwrite - to no avail.

This problem severely hinders my ability to use Ubuntu on my work machine, and I do not understand how such a problem could ship with a major release of the system. I have had no trouble with 14.04 - and I do not get an error message or are able to send a crash report.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

As I had the exact same problem, I followed the link shown by DavidKunz. I noticed they suggest using a stpf connection since passwords are send unencrypted when using ftp. So I changed to sftp and am now able to copy and paste files on the ftp server using nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not much of an useful solution to this problem, but since had exactly the same I thought you might be interested in a work-around.
[Following these instructions](http://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem) I was able to mount the ftp directory locally, thus being able to edit it in Sublime. It slower then I'm used to, but at least it's something until the Nautilus bug gets fixed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.